# How to find which line is causing the crash, the developer console log is not clear

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When my Android app crashes, it sends log to the Development Console.

Usually these logs are helpful to trace down the problem but this particular log is proving to be totally useless.

How do I find where the problem is? There is some `NullPointerException`, but it doesn't say which line of the file.

I have been trying to troubleshoot it for a while. Problem is, it doesn't happen all the time so I can't debug it. The log shows it happens somewhere in the support library, probably when attaching the fragments.

But that's the best guess I could make from this log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lifelog24.main/com.lifelog24.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lifelog24.main.h.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.n.i(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.z.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.z.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.z.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.z.j(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.s.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.q.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.lifelog24.main.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
... 11 more
```

Comment: This is because you enable proguard and need to check with your mapping file.

Comment: Take a look here how to exctract the original stracktrace: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks, let me check it.